# DC coupled amplifier circuits

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, amplifier, bjt

How can the transistors in an op amp's differential input turn on if the input voltages are smaller than \$V_{BE}\$, like 0.2V? How can the transistors in the differential amplifier start conducting with such small voltages? I understand how with AC coupling one can bias the inputs of an amplifier but I don't understand how it works with DC coupled circuits.

[image]

Comment: Transistors in a differential scheme (the first 2 transistors Q1 & Q2 in your schematic) does not turn "really" on or off. They just "conduct" a "little" more or less. For understanding more precisely, one make a "Dynamic DC" simulation with inputs at mid level voltage (which is almost 0V or quasi ground level).

Comment: Normally, the inputs are close to 0, about half way between the supply rails. Then the -5V supply in your circuit biasses the emitters -ve to supply the normal 0.6V Vbe. Now the tiny difference between inputs can turn one transistor on quite a lot harder than the other.

Comment: Vbe is not zero, instead it's 5V, which would vaporize the transistor!  Fortunately R1 prevents this.  (Don't miss the fact that Ve isn't ground.  The negative power supply sets it to around -0.6V, which makes Vbe also be ~0.6V.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if the answer is "long" ...

When components have already "good" values, it is "easy" to simulate this "simple" op-amp and determine the "steady" states values of voltage for all nodes and currents in any branch.

**DC Dynamic Analysis**

[image: DC Dynamic Analysis]

It is the **first step** (1 of 3).

Changing one input voltage (ina or inb), you can see the "behavior" of the output in "DC Dynamic" mode. Ok, you can  calculate all parameters of interest to see if all is correct, but it takes time.

The **second step** (2/3) **answer at your question**. It is DC analysis.

What you see is the behavior when **changing one input voltage (here V3)**.

And allow to view some parameters ... And specially, what is the **change of V3 needed (~ 1,279 mV)** to make a **full span of output voltage** , well below 0.2 V.

One can see the gain which is ~ -6873, slope of output Vo.

One can see that there is also an input offset voltage (~ 100 uV).

One can see that output voltage can be - 5V (to -rail), but only ~ 4.2V max(not to +rail 5V).

**DC Analysis**

[image]

**Step 3/3** ...

**AC analysis, parameter C1** (open loop, with feedback), TRAN Analysis (open loop, with feedback, only parameter offset).

**AC Open loop**

[image: AC Open loop]

**AC closed loop, 1 case**

[image: AC closed loop, 1 case]

**TRANsient Analysis open loop**

[image]

**TRANsient Analysis closed loop, 1 case**

[image: TRANient Analysis closed loop, 1 case]

Answer (score 4):

> How can the transistors in an opamps differential input turn on if the input voltages are smaller than Vbe like 0.2V.

You have hit on precisely the reason why (some) op-amps do not have rail-to-rail inputs.

In some rail-to-rail op-amps with BJT inputs, there are *two* differential pairs, configured in parallel, but with opposite polarities, for the inputs. When the voltage is too low for the npn pair, the pnp pair takes over. When the voltage is too high for the pnp pair, the npn pair takes over.

Comment: +1 for the first sentence basically answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

> *How can the transistors in an opamps differential input turn on if the
> input voltages are smaller than Vbe like 0.2V.*

For this to happen (in your circuit example) the voltages at the inputs will need to be quite close to the negative supply (-5 volts) and, of course, many op-amps just won't work within 1 volts of the negative supply voltage.

For other op-amps that use PNP input transistors, this problem occurs when the inputs are close to the positive supply rail.

> *How can the transistors in the differential amplifier start conducting
> with such small voltages.*

For most common op-amps they won't conduct and the op-amp will be non-operational or significantly impaired.

This is why we tend to use common op-amps with a nominal voltage on the inputs sat somewhere in the middle between - 5 volts and +5 volts (using your numbers) and, of course this will be around 0 volts.